# Leaflet.glify - Polygons not rendering correctly

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I have a dataset containing thousands of Car Parking Spaces I want to show on a map. However when I use the `L.glify.shapes` function the polygons do not render correctly? Is there any way I can resolve this issue?

Or can anyone recommend a different library that is more suitable for rendering large amounts of data on a leaflet map? Many thanks

You can see the code here: https://codepen.io/RayL1/pen/WNzbddJ

```
let map = L.map('map', {maxZoom: 30}).setView([ 51.524676, -0.181212], 22);

let data = {
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    { "type": "Feature", "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -0.181100, 51.524730 ], [ -0.181155, 51.524703 ], [ -0.181169, 51.524714 ], [ -0.181114, 51.524741 ], [ -0.181100, 51.524730 ] ] ] } },
    { "type": "Feature", "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -0.181158, 51.524702 ], [ -0.181212, 51.524676 ], [ -0.181226, 51.524687 ], [ -0.181172, 51.524713 ], [ -0.181158, 51.524702 ] ] ] } },
    { "type": "Feature", "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -0.181214, 51.524675 ], [ -0.181268, 51.524649 ], [ -0.181282, 51.524660 ], [ -0.181228, 51.524686 ], [ -0.181214, 51.524675 ] ] ] } },
    { "type": "Feature", "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -0.181271, 51.524648 ], [ -0.181325, 51.524622 ], [ -0.181339, 51.524633 ], [ -0.181285, 51.524659 ], [ -0.181271, 51.524648 ] ] ] } }
  ]
}
```

### This is what it should look like:

```
L.geoJSON(data, {
  style:{
    "color": "black", 
    "weight":4, 
    "fill":false, 
    "opacity":0.8
  }
}).addTo(map);
```

[image]

### This is how it comes out:

```
L.glify.shapes({
  map: map,
  data: data,
  border:true,
  color:{
    r:0,
    g:0,
    b:245
  }
});
```

[image]

### Difference:

[image]

Comment: I put the coordinates on to a google map: https://jsfiddle.net/oza8nyw3/1/

This seems to be correct. Does glify "understand" lat/longs? From experience even small distances get warped due to lat/longs being projected from a sphere to a flat plane.

Comment: Why can't you use the first method you use (which works) to draw your spaces?

Comment: Glify does use lat/longs but it's almost as if it doesn't work beyond a certain level of precision. I can't use the first method because the full dataset contains thousands of polygons, so I need a webgl renderer to display them all without performance issues.

Comment: OK, I don't understand why the first method cannot be used. Is there a limitation on how many points that can use?

Comment: Yes, beyond a certain number of points, leaflet will become very very slow and degrade the user experience. Therefore I need to render the polygons with webgl with a library like glify which can handle tens of thousands of points (or even millions) without any performance issues.

Comment: @RayLarone Did you find a solution for this issue? I am facing the same situations where I have to render thousands of polygons and glify is drawing incorrect shapes.

Comment: @ArneFischer I posted an [issue](https://github.com/robertleeplummerjr/Leaflet.glify/issues/137) to the github repo and a [pull request](https://github.com/robertleeplummerjr/Leaflet.glify/pull/138) with a potential solution. You could use my [fork of Glify](https://github.com/RayLarone/Leaflet.glify/tree/geometry-precision) which might solve the issues you are having.